# How to make every item inside a container shrink with resize CSS

Tags: html, css

So I am wondering if this approach is possible and how so.

I have a container that looks like so.

[image: enter link description here]

When I use

```
#wrapperGrid {
    display: inline-block;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 10000;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

I want every element in wrapperGrid to shrink down relative to the size wrapperGrid's height.

Right now EQCSS seems like the best option and using their element queries to detect changes in wrapperGrid and change the height and width respectively.

```
@element #wrapperGrid {
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Is using EQCSS the correct way to approach this problem and how so could I get hints in width and height changes?

Comment: You could use the bootstrap grid system to do this pretty easily without having to write your own css: https://v4alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with flexbox. By using `align-items:stretch;` you can get the child elements to resize vertically as well as horizontally.

I added another layer of divs to act as rows, otherwise you'll be fighting the width of the scrollbar creating overflow issues:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #007;
  resize: both;
  overflow:scroll;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  padding: 15px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hold on I am checking it out! I ran into the problem that every element inside the grid is a li element inside a giant ul. This is mostly for another library's functions

Comment: the principle of the solution should still hold, even when you have nested elements. you just have to identify what's acting as a row or column container and adjust the styling from there.

Comment: Could the resizing work the opposite way in the sense that after you set the height and width are you able to shrink the grid as well